# How to convert these julian dates to oracle date format?

Tags: oracle, julian-date

Below is a sample set of data that is supposed to be dates. I am not sure what kind of format it should be but I was told they are julian dates.

```
     DATE
    92017
    92320
    99002
    99003
    112010
    112011
    112012
    112013
```

Can anyone convert them into oracle dates? I tried

```
select to_date(DATE,'J') from dual
```

but some results were in the 1950s and 1940s which doesn't seen right for the data we are dealing with.
Am i doing it right here?

I also tried this formula from this link: http://www.kirix.com/stratablog/jd-edwards-date-conversions-cyyddd

```
SELECT 
TO_DATE(1900+(DATE/1000),1,1)+
TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(DATE),4))-1  FROM DUAL;
```

Thanks

Comment: According to the definition of Julian that I just looked up, this is the number of days since  January 1, 4713 BC. A quick calc of 92017/365 gives us about 252 years, which doesn't even get is into AD's yet. Use those numbers in a Julian formula and thats what you get. Perhaps you need to add another number to them first.

Comment: Im my experience, people sometimes copy this stuff from excel. Those numbers in excel translate to: 12/6/2151
10/4/2152
1/20/2171
1/21/2171
9/2/2206
9/3/2206
9/4/2206
9/5/2206 - Do these look correct for the data you are dealing with?

Comment: @Bob Thanks for the input. No, these dates should be within 10-20 years back and forth at most.

Comment: @electricllama I saw this guy uses this formula 
date(1900+(DATE/1000),1,1)+val(right(str(DATE),3))-1
which roughly translate into 
 SELECT TO_DATE(1900+(DATE/1000),1,1)+TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(DATE),4))-1 FROM DUAL;
I couldn't get it to work. Here's the http://www.kirix.com/stratablog/jd-edwards-date-conversions-cyyddd

Comment: I'm guessing they would have to be the number of days after a specific starting date. I think you should go back to the person that told you they were Julian with the definition of what Julian means and ask him to try again.

Comment: @JohnD. I added your comment to the original question. Can you please expand on "didn't work" in your original question? The official definition and the Oracle definition of julian is "since January 1, 4713". The definition in that link I think is "since 1 Jan 1900". Again if we use 92017, we get year 2152 which again appears incorrect. You need to find out your sources definition of Julian start date, and you need to confirm the numbers you have. This is not a technical issue, it's a communications issue.

Comment: @JohnD Have you tried converting it (the numbers) as epoch? Wich is the number of seconds from january 1st 1970 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

-- Using JD Edwards Date Conversions if DATE is a number

```
select to_date(to_char(1900 + floor(DATE / 1000)),'YYYY') + mod(DATE,1000) - 1 from dual;
```

-- Using JD Edwards Date Conversions if DATE is a string

```
select to_date(to_char(1900 + floor(to_number(DATE) / 1000)),'YYYY') + mod(to_number(DATE),1000) - 1 from dual;
```

Comment: There are two DATE entries in each statement, you need to replace both with the number (or string) you are using. These both work without error on Oracle 10g and Oracle 11g - I can't test them on anything else at the moment.

Comment: @bob Although the result after the data conversion does not seem right but it has nothing to do with the script. The script runs. These data are probably corrupted or I am missing something. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way that I found to convert from Julian is: -

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(your_julian_date,'JSP'),'dd-Mon-yyyy AD') AS DAY FROM dual;
```

Also, doesn't matter if the date field is number or a String. If a string, simply put the Julian date inside single quotes.

Also, the Oracle definition of Julian is 'number of days since January 1, 4712 BC'. (Many have erroneously commented as 4713 BC).
Ref: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=julian-date

Answer (score 1):

If your date field is varchar:

```
select TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(to_number('115032')+1900000),'YYYYDDD') jdedate from dual;
```

If your date fiel is a number:

```
select TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(115032+1900000),'YYYYDDD') jdedate from dual;
```

Both Return:

```
JDEDATE
-----------
01/02/2015
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple

```
select to_date('0101'|| substr(TRN_REF_NO, 8,2), 'DDMMYY') + to_number(substr(TRN_REF_NO, 10,3)) - 1 Trn_dt
```